# Inconsistent results between Rcpp and R code

Tags: r, rcpp

**UPDATE**
Previous example is complicated, hence please allow me to use a simpler example as shown below:

**Here is the Rcpp code:**

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp ;
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]  
double chooseC(double n, double k) {
  return Rf_choose(n, k);
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double function3(double n, double m, double beta) {
  double prob;
  NumericVector k(m);
  NumericVector k_vec(m);
  if(n<m){prob=0;}
  else{
    if(chooseC(n,m)==R_PosInf){
      k=seq_len(m)-1;
      k_vec= (n-k)/(m-k)*std::pow((1-beta),(n-m)/m)*beta;
          prob=std::accumulate(k_vec.begin(),k_vec.end(), 1, std::multiplies<double>())*beta;
    }
    else{ 
      prob = beta * chooseC(n,m) * std::pow(beta,m) * std::pow((1-beta),(n-m));
    }

  }
  return(prob);
}
```

**Here is the R code:**

```
function4 <- function ( n , m , beta )
{
  if ( n < m )
  {
    prob <- 0.0
  }
  else
  {
    if (is.infinite(choose(n,m))){
      k<-0:(m-1)
      prob <- beta *prod((n-k)/(m-k)*(1-beta)^((n-m)/m)*beta)
    }
    else{
      prob <- beta * choose(n,m) * beta^m * (1-beta)^(n-m)
    }
  }
  prob
}
```

**Comparison:**

```
input<-619
beta<-0.09187495

x<-seq(0, (input+1)/beta*3)
yy<-sapply(x,function(n)function3(n,input, beta=beta))
yy2<-sapply(x,function(n)function4(n,input, beta=beta))
sum(yy)=0
sum(yy2)=1
```

However， with other input:

```
input<-1
beta<-0.08214248
```

Both results are the same, `sum(yy)=sum(yy2)=0.9865887`.

I used `double` in Rcpp code, I don't know what else could cause the inconsistent precision between Rcpp and R code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `options(digits = 22)` then run the R code again ;-)

Comment: Hi! @coatless Thank you for your comment. I run that code in Rstudio, it returned the following error:                                                                       
                                                                                                                   
    ```> options(digits = 22)```
    ```> sum(yy)
     [1] 0.019373457517486758
        > sum(yy2)
      [1] 0.019373457517486748```   Actually I expected the Rcpp returns nonzero value as R code does. Do I make any mistake in Rcpp code? Thank you very much!

Comment: There are only 16 digits of precision, so don't listen to people telling you to print at 22.  The last six are random.

Comment: The question is far from minimal.  Reduce it further, please.

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel, thank you for your comment. I updated my question, I used a simpler example. These are the cases where I found the Rcpp result is not consistent with the R code result. I appreciate for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I fix the Rcpp code, so right now both Rcpp and R code produce the same results when the results are very small values. The solution is shown as below:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp ;
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]  
double chooseC(double n, double k) {
  return Rf_choose(n, k);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double function3(double n, double m, double beta) {
  double prob;
  arma::vec k = arma::linspace<vec>(0, m-1, m);
  arma::vec k_vec;

  if(n<m){prob=0;}
  else{
    if(chooseC(n,m)==R_PosInf){ 
      k_vec= (n-k)/(m-k)*pow((1-beta),(n-m)/m)*beta;  
      prob=arma::prod(k_vec)*beta;
    }
    else{ 
      prob = beta * chooseC(n,m) * pow(beta,m) * pow((1-beta),(n-m));
    }

  }
  return(prob);
}
```

However, I still do not understand why by writing code in this way will fix the precision inconsistent. `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo` still look like black boxes to me.